# Apache error: Directory index forbidden by Options directive

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to set up a git server that uses Apache for http authentication. This is a brand new install of Apache 2.2.15. When a user tries to clone a git repository, I am getting lines in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` that say

```
[error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /srv/git/
```

I am fairly certain that my `httpd.conf` file is correct, I have a section that reads

```
<Directory "/srv/git">
    Options +ExecCGI +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow, deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

There is also no other place in `httpd.conf` where Indexes is turned off.

What could be the cause of this error message?

<sub>I am posting this question because I could not find a solution to my problem on StackExchange, but I did eventually solve this problem</sub>

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to removing the file `welcome.conf' from the`etc/httpd` directory. (Or, just deleting it)

```
mkdir ~/apache_backup
mv /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf ~/apache_backup/
```

Then, check to see if that was the only file that was preventing the Indexes option. Run `grep -iR 'Indexes' /etc/httpd/*` to check which, if any files contain a line `Options -Indexes`. If they do, delete those files. `welcome.conf` has indexes turned off by default.